# Power reduction formula of $\tan^nx$ in definite integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let’s say I want to find the reduction formula for $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \tan^nx \space dx$.

I know the power reduction formula for indefinite integral of $\tan^nx$ which is $$I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac{\tan^{n-1}x}{n-1}$$ and I thought I could somehow connect this to limits of $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but I don’t know how to proceed.

Is there any other way to prove this?

Comment: Surely it is $\frac{\tan^{n-1}x}{n-1}$ not $\frac{\tan x}{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake, I will edit it

Comment: How do you prove a number?

Comment: My wording was unclear. I want to simplify the expression.

Comment: If $\int f=g+\int h$, then $\int_a^bf=g(b)-g(a)+\int_a^bh$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I_n=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^n(x)dx,$ then using the identity $\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)-1,$ we obtain

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{n-2}(x)\sec^2(x)dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{n-2}(x)dx$$
$$I_{n}+I_{n-2}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{n-2}(x)\sec^2(x)dx$$

Then using the substitution $u=\tan(x)$ the integral on the RHS becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^{n-2}(x)\sec^2(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}u^{n-2}du=\left[\frac{u^{n-1}}{n-1}\right]_{u=0}^{u=1}=\frac{1}{n-1}$$

which gives

$$I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-1},$$

and for $n=1$ we have $I_1=\frac{\ln(2)}{2},$ using the substitution $u=\cos(x)$.